# Writing a dask dataframe to parquet using to_parquet() results "RuntimeError: file metadata is only available after writer close"

Tags: python, save, dask, parquet, dask-dataframe

I am trying to use store Dask dataframe in parquet files. I have pyarrow library installed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(100000, 20)),columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
ddf.to_parquet('saved_data_prqt', compression='snappy')
```

However, I get this error as a result of my code

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArrowNotImplementedError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet.py in write_table(table, where, row_group_size, version, use_dictionary, compression, write_statistics, use_deprecated_int96_timestamps, coerce_timestamps, allow_truncated_timestamps, data_page_size, flavor, filesystem, compression_level, use_byte_stream_split, data_page_version, use_compliant_nested_type, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet.py in close(self)
    682             self.is_open = False
    683             if self._metadata_collector is not None:
--> 684                 self._metadata_collector.append(self.writer.metadata)
    685         if self.file_handle is not None:
    686             self.file_handle.close()
.................. it's a long error description which I shortened. If the whole error text required please let me know in the comments section and I'll try to add the full version.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\_parquet.pyx in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetWriter.metadata.__get__()

RuntimeError: file metadata is only available after writer close
```

Does anybody know how to debug the error and what the reason of it?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you try adding kwarg `engine="fastparquet"` to `to.parquet`?

Comment: Hi Sultan, thank you for your response. I tried and got this error AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'jitclass'

Comment: Sounds like something went wrong inside the environment. One option is to delete the environment and create a new one from scratch, preferably with the latest versions of the packages.

Comment: I installed the latest Anaconda version a week ago.  I haven't created any single custom environment. The environment I work in is the default one.

Comment: I also like to live dangerously, but when it comes to environments I learned the hard way to create custom environments for projects.

Comment: I'll try the environment proposed by Powers

Comment: Sultan please check your LinkedIn :)

Comment: I did but nothing happened...

Comment: Oh really, I sent you an invite to connect. Will try again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your exact code snippets and the Parquet files were written without any error.  This code snippet also works:

```py
ddf.to_parquet("saved_data_prqt", compression="snappy", engine="pyarrow")
```

I'm using Python 3.9.7, Dask 2021.8.1, and pyarrow 5.0.0.  What versions are you using?

Here's [the notebook](https://github.com/coiled/coiled-resources/blob/main/parquet/write-parquet-snappy.ipynb) I ran and here's [the environment](https://github.com/coiled/coiled-resources/blob/main/envs/standard-coiled.yml) if you'd like to replicate my computations exactly.

Comment: Hi Powers, thank you for your responce. I tried your snippet but it didn't work out. I'm using Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] and pyarrow '4.0.1'

Comment: @Oleg - can you try Python 3.9 and PyArrow 5?  If bumping the versions can solve the issue, that's generally the easiest fix ;)

Comment: I created an env for with Python 3.9.7 and Pyarrow pyarrow=5.0.0=py39hf9247be_8_cpu. When I run ddf.to_parquet("saved_data_prqt", compression="snappy") I get "AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'jitclass'". If I add engine="pyarrow" argument I get "RuntimeError: file metadata is only available after writer close"

Comment: Hey @Powers,  I tried to run the code on another machine with pip installation and it works on it. I gues something went wrong with my Anaconda installation. Thank you for taking the time to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error by creating an isolated virtual environment with Python 3.9 and Pyarrow 5.0 in conda followed by installation of corresponding Python kernel in Jupyter Notebook.
It's important to activate the environment in conda followed by launching Jupyter Notebook from conda otherwise (for unknow reason) if I open Jupyter Notebook from windows start menu the error persists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).